# Seeking tools to monitor file or folder creation on Windows 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I’m looking for a tool that will monitor and permit auditing of the creation of files and folders on a Windows 2008 R2 member server.

I am working with MS Support and their tools will record the ACCESS of files and folders but not the CREATION of them.

The broader issue is that someone or something is creating many folders and files at random times but there is no information about who or what created the content.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Joe S.

Comment: Trojan, Virus, Worm. Have you scanned your servers lately?

Answer (score 0):

What you need for is a [File Integrity Monitoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_integrity_monitoring) tool. Such a tool will record and possibly alert on the modification or creation of files or file attributes.

I have used AIDE several times in the past, but it only support unix-like OSes. I'd give [OSSEC](https://ossec.github.io/) a go if I were you.  I have not used it myself but it looks like it may be what you're looking for.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply enable and apply a GPO security setting to audit the object access, and then make the GPO link to the container which contains the file server that you want to audit.

How to monitor a folder and trigger a command-line action when a file is created or edited: https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created

Automate this process: http://www.fileaccessauditing.com/